# How do I publish an answer to a question I had which was not asked here?

Tags: discussion

I figured out an answer to a question, and I wanted to share it with the community. How do I do that? I posted a "question" whose body contains my suggested solution, but that seems misaligned with the process implied as I understand it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you *can* answer your own question, happens all the time.

Answer (score 3):

Questions exist for good answers, so of course it’s OK to ask a question if you already have a good answer.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

I find making the question as short as possible and the answer as detailed as needed works best, but the editing process can clean up most posts if needed later.

Just be sure that you don’t put any part of the answer in the question section - there needs to be two parts since this isn’t a forum or blog hosting service.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I followed your advice (I think ...) and posted an actual question and answer.